# Postgresql pg_cron job never executed

Tags: postgresql

I added pg_cron extension to my database (postgresql 9.6) to schedule a job.
I created a job to be executed every day at 3:30 am:

```
SELECT cron.schedule('30 3 * * *', $$create table  tbl_new as select  * from temp$$);
```

I can see that this job stored in the database:

```
mydb=# select * from cron.job;
 jobid |  schedule  |                        command                         | nodename  | nodeport |    database    | username 
-------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------+----------
     7 | 5 17 * * * | create table  tbl_new as select  * from temp | localhost |     5432 | mydb           | postgres
(1 row)
```

The problem is that the job is never executed and I there is no error in the error log.

Please advice how to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The tasks initiated by `pg_cron` must be able to connect with the
parameters mentioned in `cron.job`, **without a password**.

If steps have not been taken in `pg_hba.conf` or through a `.pgpass` file
in the server's environment to allow for that, the task won't be able to run.

Concerning the log file, error reports would be expected there, but
`pg_cron` logs at the `LOG` level. Maybe it's below your current level
(see `log_min_messages`) or there's another problem.

Comment: Also make sure it's in `shared_preload_libraries`